# How to stop streamlit from reloading the page after changing dynamically generated input fields?

Tags: python, python-3.x, streamlit

I am making a streamlit app where the user can specify how many input fields they want. The problem is that when I change the input value in any of the dynamically generated input fields, all the dynamic input fields get reset, but none of the other fields are reset. Here's the code:

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
from random import randint

@st.cache
def load_csv():
    return pd.read_csv("data.csv"), pd.read_csv("categories.csv")

df, df_cat = load_csv()

num_inputs = int(st.number_input("Number of inputs", value=1, min_value=1))

input_data = {
    "Input": [],
    "Category": [],
    "Value": []
}

for i in range(num_inputs):
    cols = st.columns(2)
    with cols[0]:
        selected = st.selectbox("Selectbox", df["Reuse"], key=i+randint(0,1000))
        input_data["Input"].append(selected)
        input_data["Category"].append(df_cat[df_cat["selection"] == selected]["Category"].to_list()[0])
    with cols[1]:
        input_data["Value"].append(st.number_input("Value", value=0, min_value=0, key=i+randint(0,1000)))

multiplier = st.number_input("Multiplier", value=0, min_value=0, key=i+randint(0,1000))

# irrelevant code from here
```

In this case, whenever I change the values of any of the dynamically generated fields, it gets reset, but I can change the value of the `multiplier` field without it getting reset. Note that changing the dynamically generated field does not affect the non-dynamically generated fields.

What am I missing here?

EDIT: I have tried using `st.form()`, it did not work.

Comment: Try to study the main concept especially the [data flow](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/get-started/main-concepts) and session state. This one too, `Streamlit reruns your entire Python script from top to bottom`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "it did not work"? st.form is probably the way to go here

Comment: Maybe you need to use two forms, potentially nested. Or you do a multipage approach: configure on page 1, save parameter to session_state and use that on page 2.